# activerecord how to query for multiple conditions on association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to make a scope for my EventsLog model which looks something along the lines of `EventsLog.with_values({"value_name" => "value", "other_value_name" => "other_value"})`.

The results of which would be the EventsLog records that have an associated EventsLogValue for each of the key-value pairs in the hash.

Here is what I have to work with.
Two tables whose definitions look like this:

```
--table for tracking events
CREATE TABLE events_log(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    event_name VARCHAR(25), --name of the event
    created_at DATETIME
);

--table for tracking the values corresponding to the event
CREATE TABLE events_log_values(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    event_id INT,
    value VARCHAR(255),
    value_name VARCHAR(25),
);
```

From these two tables two models which look like:

```
class EventsLog < BaseAPIDatabase
    self.table_name = "events_log"
    self.primary_key = "id"

    has_many :events_log_values, :foreign_key => "event_id", :primary_key => "id", :class_name => "EventsLogValue", :autosave => true

    scope :since, ->(since){ where("created_at > ?", since)}
    scope :named, ->(event_name){ where(:event_name => event_name) }


    def values
        events_log_values.inject({}) do |hsh, v|
            hsh.merge({v.value_name => v.value})
        end
    end

end


class EventsLogValue < BaseAPIDatabase
    self.table_name = "events_log_values"
    self.primary_key = "id"

end
```

My approach so far has been to try and create a function that returns an active record relation which has applied one key-value pair at a time and then later to add a scope (or probably just a class method returning a relation) which chains them for me (something along the lines of `scope :with_values, ->(values){values.inject(self){|slf, (k, v)| slf.with_value(k, v)} }`).

Originally I tried to implement with_value as a fairly standard scope, `scope :with_value, ->(val_name, val){ eager_load(:events_log_values).where(:events_log_values => {:value_name => val_name, :value => val}) }`, which works fine by itself but when chained results in a single join with multiple conditions on the joined values.

Deciding that this would be solved by joining the values table with an alias for each condition; my new approach has been to define a has_many association in my with_value function then to eager_load that association and to add a where condition based on each new association:

```
def self.with_value(val_name, val)
    has_many val_name.to_sym, ->(){ where(:value_name => val_name) }, :foreign_key => "event_id", :primary_key => "id", :class_name => "EventsLogValue"
    res = eager_load(:events_log_values)
    res.eager_load(val_name.to_sym).where("#{val_name.pluralize}_events_log" => {:value => val})
end
```

This actually works pretty well but has a few problems.  The first one being that I have a difficult time knowing what the name in the where condition is going to be for the association. The second (and bigger problem) being that my values function now only has whatever value_names have not had an association made for them.

Here is some sql which was generated by the multiple has_manys and may help to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
EventsLog.with_values("hello" => "world", "foo" => "bar").to_sql
SELECT ...
FROM [events_log] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [events_log_values] ON [events_log_values].[event_id] = [events_log].[id] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [events_log_values] [hellos_events_log] ON [hellos_events_log].[event_id] = [events_log].[id] AND [hellos_events_log].[value_name] = 'hello' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [events_log_values] [foos_events_log] ON [foos_events_log].[event_id] = [events_log].[id] AND [foos_events_log].[value_name] = 'foo' 
WHERE [hellos_events_log].[value] = 'world' AND [foos_events_log].[value] = 'bar'
```

How can I go about getting a record which has several associated records meeting several separate conditions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I have been able to come up with since asking my question.  It uses arel to generate sql joins with aliases for each of the values and also generates a where condition for each value.

It's not the cleanest thing but it seems to get the job done.

```
def self.with_values(values)
    el = EventsLog.arel_table
    arel_joins = el
    arel_wheres = []

    values.each do |k, v|
        ev = EventsLogValue.arel_table.alias("#{k}_join")

        arel_joins = arel_joins.join(ev).on(el[:id].eq(ev[:event_id]).and(ev[:value_name].eq(k)))
        arel_wheres << ev[:value].eq(v)
    end

    arel_wheres.inject(EventsLog.joins(arel_joins.join_sources)){|rel, con| rel.where(con)}
end
```

p.s. I think I read somewhere that Model.arel_table is undocumented and should not be used?  It may be prudent to use Arel::Table.new('table_name') instead.